# keystroke for Skim's bookmark search

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, sonoma, skim

Before updating to MacOS `Sonoma` I could use the keystroke

```
CMD+SHIFT+/
```

to search quickly for `Skim's bookmarks`. Now, on `Sonoma`, it seems broken and a `Help panel` opens instead.

How can one jump directly into the Skim's search field?